# laravel customize default form validation in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Where can i find the blade form form validation rules for the default registration page where it says this field is required if i do not enter the email.

### blade file

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control 
    @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

 @error('email')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
 @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: Does it help?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

Comment: `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php` on `validator` function

Comment: @sta is that not the sever side validation it seems the validation is done on the client side even if i remove the validation  on validator it still says "please fill out this field"

Comment: The "client side" validation you are talking about is built-in browser validation using the attribute `required` on any field. Nothing to do with Laravel/Blade.

Comment: @kerbh0lz thanks i did not notice that i was busy looking elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php` and below is the code of it:

```
 /**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

you can customize the error messages as well in the third parameter of **make** method.

Comment: The validation  for that message "please fill out this field "might be on the client side because it happens even before the form hits the server. I tried removing the validation on validator but it still says please fill out this field

Comment: you should remove the required attribute from the element.